# How to implement Marathon test runner?

Tags: android, automated-tests

I have many UI tests written in Espresso framework. And now I'm trying to implement Marathon Test Runner in my project.
I added in dependency.gradle

```
ext.Versions = [
        marathon : "0.5.0",
        ...
]
ext.TestLibraries = [
    marathon : "com.malinskiy.marathon:marathon-gradle-plugin:$Versions.marathon",
    ...
]
```

then i added in all my projects gradle

```
androidTestImplementation TestLibraries.marathon
```

Unfortunately i get next error

```
Execution failed for task ':mobile:mergeDevDebugAndroidTestNativeLibs'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':mobile:devDebugAndroidTestRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform artifact 'common.jar (com.android.tools:common:26.3.0)' to match attributes {artifactType=android-java-res, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: /home/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools/common/26.3.0/1d9b4db75bbe5fe357c8a56db506f2361ebd508d/common-26.3.0.jar.
         > Failed to transform '/home/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools/common/26.3.0/1d9b4db75bbe5fe357c8a56db506f2361ebd508d/common-26.3.0.jar' using Jetifier. Reason: The given artifact contains a string literal with a package reference 'android.support.design.widget' that cannot be safely rewritten. Libraries using reflection such as annotation processors need to be updated manually to add support for androidx.. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)
```

Please can anybody help me what do i do wrong. How to implement it, did i miss something?

Answer (score 0):

From the provided config it seems like you're using the gradle plugin version of marathon. Please check out the docs on how [to apply gradle plugins](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html)

What you're trying here is to apply gradle plugin via dependency to the test apk